# JqueryMobile Table with a Linebreak in a filled Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a question related to the jQuery Mobile table.
I have a table that looks like this (In the code below), which is horizontal scrollable with a fixed header using [floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/).
 And some of the "td" text can be really long  for example like a article discription.
At the moment it just uses the full space and adds no 'br' whatsoever.
 And with that behaviour it reduces the available space of the other elements. And by the way the content will be added dynamically.

 My question is now, is it possible to force a line break in that long "td" text if the text gets to long? Sort of a br inside the table cell?

```
 <div id="containerDiv">
<table class="ui-responsive ui-shadow gk-decorate tableClass" id="tableId" is="jqm-table" data-role="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="1"><abbr>Header 1</abbr></th>
      <th data-priority="1"><abbr>Header 2</abbr></th>
      <th data-priority="1"><abbr>Header 3</abbr></th>
      <th data-priority="1"><abbr>Header 4</abbr></th>
      <th data-priority="1"><abbr>Header 5</abbr></th>
      <th data-priority="1"><abbr>Header 6</abbr></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="someId">
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>LooooooongContent</td>
      <td>RealllllllyLooooongContent</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr id="someId">
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>LooooooongContent</td>
      <td>RealllllllyLooooongContent</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr id="someId">
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>LooooooongContent</td>
      <td>RealllllllyLooooongContent</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="someId">
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>LooooooongContent</td>
      <td>RealllllllyLooooongContent</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="someId">
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>LooooooongContent</td>
      <td>RealllllllyLooooongContent</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As things currently stand, the `<table>` is trying to resize the cells perfectly because there are no width's set, you can do this by setting width's on the `<th>` tags. Doing this will make elements with white space automatically go on to a new line in a `<br />` like fashion.

As you don't seem to have white space in your example. You can use `word-break` like so:

```
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

I have provided an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akrvqk) where I cheekily don't add width's to the `<th>` tags and be lazy and add a width to the table, but you can see the result of using `word-break`

Comment: Hey thank you thats pretty much it, wow. Is there any way to set that break after a certain word or after a space is that possible?

Comment: If you have spaces in the text and your table has some kind of set width it should naturally breakdown at the space. It's just a case of adding `width`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt do that naturally even after a set width :(. It just cuts off the word if needed but there is probably some question in that regard in here.

Comment: I have edited my [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjRZQV) to add percentage `width` to the `<th>` tags and I've added spaces to the words and as you can see it line breaks if the field isn't long enough. I've commented out the `word-break` as it wouldn't be needed if you have spaces.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to remove the word-break.